# how I can make a column pair with respect of a group?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, group-by, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe and an `id` column as a group. For each `id` I want to pair its elements in the following way:

```
title     id
sal        1
summer     1
fada       1
row        2
winter     2
gole       2
jack       3
noway      3
```

output

```
title     id     pair
sal        1      None
summer     1      summer,sal
fada       1      fada,summer
row        2      None
winter     2      winter, row
gole       2      gole,winter
jack       3      None
noway      3      noway,jack
```

As you can see in the output, we pair from the last element of the group `id`, with an element above it. Since the first element of the group does not have a pair I put `None`. I should also mention that this can be done in `pandas` by the following code, but I need `Pyspark` code since my data is big.

```
df=data.assign(pair=data.groupby('id')['title'].apply(lambda x: x.str.cat(x.shift(1),sep=',')))

                    |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't emphasise more that a Spark dataframe is an unordered collection of rows, so saying something like "the element above it" is undefined without a column to order by. You can fake an ordering using `F.monotonically_increasing_id()`, but I'm not sure if that's what you wanted.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window

w = Window.partitionBy('id').orderBy(F.monotonically_increasing_id())

df2 = df.withColumn(
    'pair', 
    F.when(
        F.lag('title').over(w).isNotNull(),
        F.concat_ws(',', 'title', F.lag('title').over(w))
    )
)

df2.show()
+------+---+-----------+
| title| id|       pair|
+------+---+-----------+
|   sal|  1|       null|
|summer|  1| summer,sal|
|  fada|  1|fada,summer|
|  jack|  3|       null|
| noway|  3| noway,jack|
|   row|  2|       null|
|winter|  2| winter,row|
|  gole|  2|gole,winter|
+------+---+-----------+
```

Comment: I can't reproduce your solution. The row order in the end result is wrong.

Comment: yes, the row order is different because there is no ordering defined in the question. It's not a very good question really, but I'm just trying to help.

Comment: Why does PySpark mess up the order and why do you use this `monotonically_increasing_id` method?

Comment: Because there is no inherent ordering in a Spark dataframe. Dataframes are distributed data structures without ordering, and they could end up in any order due to shuffle in window functions.

Comment: I used that because I needed an order by in the `lag` function, but there is nothing to order by in the OP's question.

Comment: The `pair` column is made correctly. but it makes other columns null!

Comment: @elham please, whenever you have unexpected results, don't just shout. Calm down, and provide the code and data that caused an issue.

Comment: why my _c1 ,_c2 and num columns were changed?

Comment: I just noticed that it shuffles the data. that's what I confused. can I keep order?

Comment: @elham Spark dataframe is an unordered collection of rows. If your data has no column to order by, it is not possible to maintain the order. If you know how your dataframe was ordered, you can use that in the Window order by definition.